# Send events from background task to UI

Tags: win-universal-app, background-task

I have implemented an application in windows phone 10.

In my background task, while the application is working some jobs, it wants to call to the main project and update UI real time.

Is there any mechanism to send event from background task to the main project  for updating UI ?

Answer (score 0):

```
         //backTask
            await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
            () =>
            {
                //update ui
                UIAction.?Invoke();
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any mechanism to send event from background task to the main project for updating UI ?

You can register the `Completed` event of the background task and update the UI in the `Completed` event:

Register the complete event:

```
var registration= taskBuilder.Register();
registration.Completed += Registration_Completed;

private async void Registration_Completed(BackgroundTaskRegistration sender, BackgroundTaskCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    var settings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        tbResult.Text=settings.Values["BackgroundResult"].ToString();
    });
}
```

Xaml:

```
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Name="btnRegister" Click="btnRegister_Click">
            Click Me to register BT
        </Button>
        <TextBlock Name="tbResult">
            Here will show the result
        </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

And here is the complete demo: [BackgroundTaskSample](https://github.com/elvisxia/BackgroundCallbackSample).

Comment: CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow